# How to setup npm dependencies updating in Intellij on win10

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm

I'm using Windows 10, IntelliJ 2020.1 and Node 12
When I run "npm install" from the terminal inside IntelliJ, everything installs like normal. However, when I make an edit to my package.json file and click "Run 'npm install" in the popup in the lower right corner, I receive the follow error:

```
Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\me\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.4 C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Am I overlooking a simple IntelliJ config setting?  Appreciate any help.

====
[image]

and the last entry in the log before the error mentioned above:

````
    at com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.packages.NodePackageUtil.doLoadPackageInfo(NodePackageUtil.java:112)
    at com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.packages.NodePackageUtil.loadPackageInfo(NodePackageUtil.java:71)
    at com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.settings.NodePackageInfoManager$1.fetch(NodePackageInfoManager.java:23)
    at com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.settings.NodePackageInfoManager$1.fetch(NodePackageInfoManager.java:19)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.bower.cache.PrevRequestSkippingCache.lambda$fetchSync$2(PrevRequestSkippingCache.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.bower.cache.PrevRequestSkippingCache.fetchSync(PrevRequestSkippingCache.java:92)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.bower.cache.PrevRequestSkippingCache.lambda$fetchAsync$1(PrevRequestSkippingCache.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:210)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-04-27 18:45:43,643 [101269107]   WARN - ckaging.InstalledPackagesPanel - Cannot fetch the latest version of the installed package npm 
com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.packages.NodePackageInfoException: FAILED COMMAND: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js info --json npm
EXIT CODE: 1```
````

Comment: please share a screenshot of **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** page and kidea.log (**Help > Show Log in Explorer**)

Comment: @lena I've updated my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `npm.cmd` as a **Node.js interpreter**, but it's not an interpreter, it's a package manager run with Node.js. Please specify a valid path to `node.exe` - must be `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`